# Get a python map with the title of the column and the column of data from a data file

Tags: python, file, csv, dictionary, numpy

I have a file with the following format :

```
# a, b, c
0.1   0   0
0.2 0.4 0.5
  4   5 0.9
0.3   0  10
```

which is a file with 3 columns of data and the name of these columns are `a`, `b` and `c`.

Currently to read these data, I use :

```
def readdata(filename):
    a, b, c = np.loadtxt(filename, unpack=True)
    return a, b, c
```

But instead of that, I would like `readdata` to return a map `mydata` with `{column title, numpy array}` so I can call `mydata["a"]` to get the first column. I want this function to work if the file has new columns (`d, e, f...`).

How to do that (avoiding unecessary copies as possible) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is provided by the numpy function [`np.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), if you call it with the keyword `names=True`.

Example:

```
>>> s = """# a, b, c
... 0.1 0 0
... 0.2 0.4 0.5
... 4 5 0.9
... 0.3 0 10
... """
>>> data = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(s),names=True)
>>> data['a']
array([ 0.1,  0.2,  4. ,  0.3])
>>> data['b']
array([ 0. ,  0.4,  5. ,  0. ])
>>> data['c']
array([  0. ,   0.5,   0.9,  10. ])
```

Answer (score 1):

With this file:

```
#a, b, c
0.1   0   0
0.2 0.4 0.5
  4   5 0.9
0.3   0  10
```

Assuming your first line defines header rows, in Numpy, you can do this:

First, read the header row:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/testnp.txt','r') as f:
...    header=[n.strip() for n in f.readline().strip().lstrip('#').split(',')]
... 
>>> header
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Now, create a structured array in Numpy with the names the same as the fields in the header:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> struct=[(name,'float') for name in header]
>>> data=np.loadtxt('/tmp/testnp.txt',dtype=struct,comments='#')
>>> data
array([(0.1, 0.0, 0.0), (0.2, 0.4, 0.5), (4.0, 5.0, 0.9), (0.3, 0.0, 10.0)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8')])
>>> data['a']
array([ 0.1,  0.2,  4. ,  0.3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read your file into a [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) DataFrame with

```
import pandas
dataframe = pandas.read_csv(my_file)
```

then you get your columns just doing:

```
my_column_series = dataframe['column_name']
```

note that your csv file has to have a first row (header) with the column_name's. Otherwise you have to give the names to the dataframe manually.